# Is it possible to prevent Xcode from listing build errors in a separate window?

Tags: xcode

I don't like the way Xcode displays compile errors and highlights source code in a separate floating Build Results window. It's easy to end up with 3 text editors on screen, all showing the same source code! I just want it to jump to my error in the main text editor like Visual Studio would. Is there a way around this, or is it any different in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, select the "All in one" layout in XCode General Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xcode 4 is all one window, and builds constantly so errors appear almost immediately. I think you'll like it much better, especially if you're accustomed to Visual Studio (it's not the same as VS, mind you, but more similar than Xcode 3).

Answer (score -1):

No way mate, I was a .net developer before I switched to mac. It's very hard to get use to Xcode and Objective C, it's not as intuitive as Visual Studio , or C sharp.

However the latest version of Xcode brings some improvements , so it doesn't show you the compiler errors in a separate window. It shows you the errors in the left side and the code in the editor. you should upgrade it's a bit more intuitive.